# Programmatically set height of collapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Basically, I have a collapsingToolbarLayout with an imageview in the paralax section.  This image is guaranteed to be square, and I want to display the whole image, so I need to set the height of the collapsingToolbarLayout to be equal to the width.  How can I accomplish this?  For some reason wrap_content on the imageView and coordinatorlayout is not making it actually wrap the content.  Note that I am using Glide to load the image from a network resource, so I don't have it when the activity starts.

Current Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="140dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="90dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
            <ImageView
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:transitionName="pic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:id="@+id/smallicon"/>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:padding="20dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/artist"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textSize="24sp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:id="@+id/date"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:transitionName="bottom">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Start with `findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout)` then see if you can use something around `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: I tried doing 

        `Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        Point size = new Point();

        display.getSize(size);

        collapsingToolbarLayout.setLayoutParams(new    ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size.x, size.x));`
But that doesn't work either

Comment: Wouldn't that set the view to 0 width and height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you probably just want to add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView`. As per the [documentation of adjustViewBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds)

> Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

If you leave it false (the default), then the `ImageView` will not resize when Glide later loads the image.